# How to reverse byte[]<=>double[] in java

Tags: java, double, byte

In java.
I had some file (*.wav) from where I extracted byte[]. After that I converted this to double[] by this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytesIn.length && idx < buffer.length; i += 2) 
         {
           byte lowByte = bytesIn[i];
           byte highByte = bytesIn[i+1];

//Little endian
           buffer[idx++] = (lowByte & 0xFF | highByte << 8);     
         }
```

Where bytesIn = byte[] of file
and buffer = double[]

After this I did some operation on buffer used fast Fourier transform and inverse. Now after inverse operation from fft I have double[] but I dont know how to get back to byte[].

I found this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(value);
```

but bytes store different value than I expected. Changed buffer after IFFT is same as original one. Can anyone write how to reverse code from first code block?

Comment: I'm wondering about sign extension issues for `highByte`. What happens if you use `(highByte & 0xFF) << 8` instead of `highByte << 8`?

Comment: You definitely should not be using ByteBuffer.  Your double values are *mathematically* equivalent to 16-bit values, but each double value’s bits do not represent the original two bytes.